# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object wirth whis json

Tags: c#, arrays, json, deserialization

```
{
    "token": "d10e",
    "@version": "1",
    "key": "30a8-e2dc2c6c7a5e",
    "result": [
        ["name :Customer10", "description :Hesco"],
        ["name :Customer16", "description :IoTLab"],
        ["name :Customer32", "description :Abdevand"],
        ["name :Customer20", "description :Jahad Daneshgahi KNU"],
        ["name :Customer8", "description :Babinab"],
        ["name :Customer4", "description :ISA"],
        ["name :ParsIoT", "description :customer created on 2018-01-16T05:45:05.939 (BSS Time)"],
        ["name :Customer18", "description :Customer18"]
    ]
}
```

**how can i deserialize  to json array??**

C# return error and can not deserialize this json !!!

```
var resp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Organization>>(response);
```

This is the organization class , and how can i list result object

```
public class Organization
{
    [JsonProperty("token")]
    public string token { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@version")]
    public string version { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@timestamp")]
    public string timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public Result[] result { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the Result class:

```
public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That JSON simply isn't valid - each `[...]` within the result array should be `{...}`, so I'm not surprised that whatever you're using to deserialize it is complaining. Beyond the broken JSON, we can't tell what code you're trying to use to deserialize or the error you're seeing. Note that the JSON you've posted isn't an array itself - it *contains* an array. So I'd expect you to deserialize it to a single object and then extract the array as the value of the `result` property - once the JSON itself is valid, of course.

Comment: Change `[ ]` to `{ }`  in elements of result attribute

Comment: @DaisyShipton yes i know , but why this site(https://jsonlint.com/) validate this json ??

Comment: Ah, hang on - it *is* valid JSON... I've just spotted where the quotes are. It's a bit odd though, with values of "name :Customer10" etc. So at this point, the problem is that we don't know what code you've tried or what error you're seeing. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Hossein: Look closely at the values - they're just string values of the form "key: value". They're not JSON properties. Fooled me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems:

- You're trying to deserialize to a `List<Organization>`, but your JSON only represents a *single* `Organization`.
- The `result` property is an array of arrays of strings - the JSON doesn't contain any "name" or "description" properties, just values that look like "name :Customer20" etc.

Here's a complete example that *does* work:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Organization
{
    [JsonProperty("token")]
    public string Token { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("@version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public string[][] Results { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var org = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Organization>(json);
        Console.WriteLine($"Token: {org.Token}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Version: {org.Version}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Key: {org.Key}");
        Console.WriteLine("Result entries:");
        foreach (string[] entry in org.Results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", entry));
        }
    }
}
```

But now you'll need to parse each entry in the `result` array individually. (If you can modify the format of the JSON, it would be better if each entry were an object, but the code above deals with the JSON as you've presented it.)